# Get all elements with count less than 50 from a counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter, python-itertools

Code

```
from itertools import dropwhile
for key, count in dropwhile(lambda key_count: key_count[1] < 50, countered.most_common()):
    del countered[key]
```

Input which is the `countered` variable looks like this

```
[('Required Weather API', 100),
 ('New York City Museums', 70),
 ('New York City Art Galleries', 48),
 ('Zillow Home Value Searching API', 38)]
```

I used the code above to get the items with count less than 50 into a list but I get an empty counter back `Counter()`

Expected output

```
[('New York City Art Galleries', 48),
 ('Zillow Home Value Searching API', 38)]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems complicated. Why not use:

```
res = [item for item in countered if item[1]<50]
```

gives

```
[('New York City Art Galleries', 48), ('Zillow Home Value Searching API', 38)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`dropwhile()` is giving you a list of items not deleted but you use that as a basis for `del`

You want one strategy or the other.  If you want `dropwhile()` try:

```py
from itertools import dropwhile
from collections import Counter

countered = Counter()
countered["Required Weather API"] = 100
countered["New York City Museums"] = 70
countered["New York City Art Galleries"] = 48
countered["Zillow Home Value Searching API"] = 38
countered = list(dropwhile(lambda row: row[1] > 50, countered.items()))
print(countered)
```

However, I prefer the strategy given by @user19077881 (and voted for it)